# How to wait for ObservableAsPropertyHelper update in ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, .net, reactiveui

I have a method in which I change property which triggers a change on other property which backing field is `ObservableAsPropertyHelper` type. Additionally filed which is `ObservableAsPropertyHelper` triggers a nested view change, so it takes some time to be activated. Until is activated I have a null in property which depends on `ObservableAsPropertyHelper` and I need wait, but I don't know how.

I have a sample code.

```
public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private string _carModelName;
    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<ICarModel> _carViewModel;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.LoadConfigurationCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(this.LoadConfiguration);

        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.CarModelName)
            .Select<string, ICarModel>(x =>
            {
                switch (x)
                {
                    case "VW":
                        return new VWModel();
                    case "BMW":
                        return new BMWViewModel();
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            })
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.CarViewModel, out _carViewModel);

        this.CarModelName = "VW";
    }

    public string CarModelName
    {
        get => _carModelName;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _carModelName, value);
    }

    public ICarModel CarViewModel => _carViewModel.Value;

    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> LoadConfigurationCommand { get; }        

    private LoadConfiguration()
    {
        // code which loads configuration

        this.CarModelName = configurationCarModelName; // "BMW"

        // now I want to call CarViewModel, but I have null, because modification of property is in progress
        this.CarViewModel as ICarModel;
        this.CarViewModel.Load(configurationObject);

        // how to wait for CarViewModel update to call Method with parameters?
    }
}
```

Comment: I would probably add a configuration field that gets populated by the command and do a WhenAnyValue on the CarViewModel property to load the config into the car whenever the car changes.

Comment: @ColtBauman I will try do it like you wrote. It sound doable. Maybe it's not a clean approach (field only to store a new state), but main goal is to have a working code.

Answer (score 2):

So, you can react to the change and just invoke the command.  Once you start down the declarative path, you just have to declare what things should happen in response to other things.  So "When my VM property changes, I want to do these things."

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.CarModelName)
.Select<string, ICarModel>(x =>
{
    switch (x)
    {
        case "VW":
            return new VWModel();
        case "BMW":
            return new BMWViewModel();
        default:
            return null;
    }
})
.InvokeCommand(this, x => x.CarViewModel.Thing);

public interface ICarModel
{
    ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> Thing { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I made an edit to my question. I call command `LoadConfigurationCommand` which reads new value for `CarModelName` and has data which should be passed to re-created `CarViewModel`. I don't see still how to solve this.

Comment: I'm not sure it changes my answer that much.  In Reactive Programming you're not waiting, your reactive.  So when the value changes, invoke the command.

Comment: So I need change code flow. Method `LoadConfiguration` currently can't change `CarModelName` and call method on `CarViewModel`, because second one is not updated yet. Going back to your example - not all change on `CarModelName` should call `CarViewModel.Thing`.

Comment: So filter them with a `Where` clause so it only happens in your specific use case?  Based on what you provided, this solves the problem.  We are invoking a command in response to the value getting set.

Comment: I don't know how to filter. I can create method which will return configuration, but how then change CarModelName and then wait for CarViewModel change to apply second part of configuration. I didn't found similar example code nor in documentation, nor in samples. How call method which returns results and then fill in good moments rest properties?